# using SharpPcap with usp 3G modem

Tags: modem, 3g, sharppcap

I have learned SharpPcap to capturing packet from a particular network interface.  The following code is used to get all network interfaces on local machine:

```
foreach (PcapDevice dev in CaptureDeviceList.Instance)
    Console.WriteLine(dev.ToString());
```

but when I plug my usp 3G modem and run the above program, the list returned does not contain a line for the usp 3G modem.

How do I apply the packet capture on this 3G modem?

Comment: Have you tried capturing on this adapter with Wireshark? SharpPcap uses libpcap/winpcap like Wireshark does. If Wireshark can capture on this device, SharpPcap can as well.

Answer (score 0):

EDIT: I have found one way of doing this. I would love it if someone has something better, because this does require a commercial product. CommView from Tamosoft allows you to capture Verizon Aircard packets. (Can't speak to anything else...)

[CommView by Tamosoft](http://www.tamos.com/products/commview/)

They have a free version which you can use to test with (it only captures every other packet). It's about $250.

---

### Previous Answer

@ Chris Morgan

Unfortunately, modems are seen a PPP connections, which are not supported on Windows XP, Windows Vista, or Windows 7 at the network adapter level. Therefore, winPCap, Wireshark, etc, will not see the traffic.

See Question #5 of the FAQ:

[WinpCap FAQ](http://winpcap.org/misc/faq.htm#Q-5)